Performance Comparison "queryAnsiSql" vs "queryAnsiSqlV2"
I came across the blog post Unlocking the Power of Apex in Salesforce Data Cloud, Part 1 and experimented with queryAnsiSqlV2. Interestingly, I observed that the execution time for queryAnsiSqlV2 was initially higher compared to queryAnsiSql (screenshots attached). However, when rerunning the same queries, the execution time for both methods significantly reduced.

Could this behavior indicate that results are being cached? If so, is there any documentation or details available about how this caching mechanism operates?
